# Understanding Electromagnetic Induction and Lenz's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

I am having trouble understanding the concept of electromagnetic induction and its application, particularly in regards to Lenz's law. I am having trouble visualizing the relationship between the magnetic field and induced current, and how Lenz's law affects this relationship.

I understand Faraday's states that a magnetic field can be generated in a current carrying wire, which is just electromagnetic induction. But, I don't understand why it opposes the change in magnetic flux, to thereby reduce it, and to in turn, via Newton's third law, produce an opposing force of equal magnitude. I am lacking an, overall, understanding of magnetic fields.

Can someone provide a clear explanation of these concepts, including examples and context that can help me better understand how they work in real-world situations? Any resources or suggestions for further study would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Changing magnetic field induces electric field around the change.  This is the basis of Faraday's Law.  When expanded to macroscopic scale, changing magnetic flux through a conductor induces emf around the changing flux.  This emf results from the induced electric field.

The emf in a conductor causes charge to move within the conductor.  This is electric current.  Electric current (i.e. moving electric charge) is one of the two primary sources of magnetic field.  (Note that the other is changing electric flux, often called displacement current.)  The magnetic field produced by the induced current is around the current.  It will therefore either support or oppose the existing change of magnetic flux.

If supporting the change, the change of flux will grow, the emf will grow, the current will grow, and then the magnetic flux change will grow more.  The system will increase without bound.  If opposing the change of flux, the induced magnetic field will reduce the change of flux, thus reducing the induced emf and current.  Energy is transferred from whatever causes the original change of magnetic flux into the surrounding conductor.  Magnetic energy becomes electric energy.